# How to define max size in ExpiringMap

Tags: java, apache, maven, caching

How to define max size in [ExpiringMap](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap). I want to ensure that not more N messages are stored in the ExpiringMap at a time.

```
ExpirationListener listener = new ExpirationListener();
ExpiringMap<String, String> map = ExpiringMap.builder()
                    .expiration(180, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .expirationPolicy(ExpiringMap.ExpirationPolicy.CREATED)
                    .expirationListener(listener)
                    .build();
```

So, I want to specify that after 180 second only next value to be inserted to this map.

NOTE : There are multiple threads that are writing to this Map. So it need to be thread safe too.

Say MSG1 comes at 0th second and MSG1 comes at 1st second and MSG2 comes at 2nd second then after 180seconds I should be able to add one message and after 181st second I should be able to add one more message.

As the older ones keep on expiring and deleting from the map.

How this can be achieved? Please help.
I read the documentation, they don't have any function to define the MAX_SIZE

Comment: This feature is described in [issue #16](https://github.com/jhalterman/expiringmap/issues/16) with a request for contribution. You would have to use a different library, like [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) or [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), or implement it yourself.

Comment: @BenManes In Guava can we delete a key value after expiring ? I tried with Loading Cache in Guava, but they don't provide this. One need to regularly clean the cache.

Comment: In that design it is amortized and lazily handled to avoid dedicated threads. You can call cleanUp() periodically with a ScheduledExecutor to improve responsiveness, but that's rarely necessary.

Comment: @BenManes Then what else is the way that can ensure that If I try to put more messages then MAX SIZE it should not insert them or throw some Exception. Can you provide me a piece of code ? I tried but LoadingCache even dont provide exact count of elements in it. So didn't worked out for me.

Comment: An exact count isn't possible with concurrency. Guava evicts early and never exceeds, Caffeine at the threshold and may temporarily exceed. But a cache will insert new arrivals and evict, rather than not admit. If you want a cap that rejects then you'd want to write some custom code.